# Why does this code require me to include the size of the array in the function declaration?

Tags: arrays, function, go

I am trying to pass a float64 array to a function that will add the values and return the sum. My code is as follows:

```golang
func addThemNumbers(numbers []float64)  float64{
    sum := 0.0 
    for _,value := range numbers {
        sum += value 
    }
    return sum
}
func main() { 
    favNums := [2]float64 {0.9, 1.997}
    fmt.Println("Sum: ", addThemNumbers(favNums))
}
```

When I run this, it produces this error:

```
/main.go:33:40: cannot use favNums (type [2]float64) as type []float64 in argument to addThemNumbers
```

However, when I specify size 2 in my function, such that `addThemNumbers(numbers [2]float64)`, there is no error and it runs. If there was a type mismatch, I don't understand why specifying the size of the array works. I've seen several examples where specifying the size of the array in the function was not needed, so what am I missing?

Comment: `[2]float64` and `[]float64` are two distinct types. One is an array of a constant size of 2 the other one is a *slice* not an array. https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Comment: The difference between a slice and an array is pretty fundamental in Go. Please work through the Tour of Go once more: It explains most fundamentals pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[2]float64` is an array. When you declare a function `f([2]float64)`, you can only pass a `[2]float64` type value to it, and when you do, it passes a copy of the whole array. An array is a fixed size structure.

`[]float64` is a slice. It is essentially a struct containing a pointer to an array, its length, and capacity. A slice contains a pointer to an array, so if you have a function `f([]float64)`, you can pass any size array to it, and a reference to the underlying array will be passed, not a copy of that array.

To convert an array to a slice, you can use `arr[:]`. In your program:

```
    fmt.Println("Sum: ", addThemNumbers(favNums[:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a difference between array and slice. I think what you're looking for is a slice.

In the function parameter, you're expecting a slice but rather you passed an array.

There are two ways to deal with it, quickly:

> 1. To remove the type mismatch, do mention the size in the parameter so that it accepts an array now (not slice).
> 2. Convert your array to a slice

```golang
fmt.Println("Sum: ", addThemNumbers(favNums[:]))
```

Also, please read this article on [slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we looking at the []float64 & [2]float64 is looking the same. But there's a difference, that is []float64 is a slice & [2]float64 is an array.

So when you change the addThemNumbers(numbers [2]float64), it automatically turns to an array. So you able to run the program without error.

And if you want to convert an array to a slice you can try below code.

```
func addThemNumbers(numbers []float64)  float64{
    sum := 0.0
    for _,value := range numbers {
        sum += value
    }
    return sum
}
func main() {
    favNums := [2]float64 {0.9, 1.997}
    fmt.Println("Sum: ", addThemNumbers(favNums[:]))
}
```